# GN build guide for cobalt

Tags: cobalt, gn

The development site page and the default README.md file describe how to create cobalt based on "GYP". However, I am wondering if it can be made of "GN" like chrome.
I found the gn build guide (https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/doc/gn_quick_start.md) in the cobalt's doc directory, but it gives me an error in my dev environment. I will check what the problem is. But first of all, I want to know if "GN" can officially make cobalt.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Cobalt cannot be built with GN. GYP is your only option.